# Desktop notification win10toast image not working

Tags: python-3.x

I have a puppies.ico image file in the same directory as my script but when I try to use it, it gives me an error.

Here is the error:

> ERROR:root:Some trouble with the icon (C:/private-stuff/puppies.ico): (0, 'LoadImage', 'No error message is available')

Here is my code:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast("Puppies", "Puppies are the best", icon_path="puppies.ico", duration=20)
```

Comment: I am having same issue... can any have a solution for this? I am using it on Windows 10 Pro 20H2